# Mutually Recursive Function to Compare Trees

Tags: coq

I am trying to write a comparison function over a tree like type.

It has a value which should be a string, but to keep things simple I made it a nat for now. It also has a hash to help speed up comparison, which will later be replaced with a Sint63, but again to keep things simple for now, I made it a nat.

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import Coq.Lists.List.ListNotations.

Inductive Info: Type :=
  mkInfo :
    forall
    (value: nat)
    (children: list Info)
    (hash: nat),
  Info.
```

The comparison function has to short circuit as quickly as possible, for this it tries to use the hash or value before it tries the children. Using the hash might result in an order that might not be pleasing to the eye, but the only important thing is that the order is deterministic as quick.

```
Fixpoint compare_info (x y: Info) {struct x} :=
  match x with
  | mkInfo xvalue xchildren xhash =>
    match y with
    | mkInfo yvalue ychildren yhash =>
      match Nat.compare xhash yhash with
      | Lt => Lt
      | Gt => Gt
      | Eq =>
        match Nat.compare xvalue yvalue with
        | Lt => Lt
        | Gt => Gt
        | Eq => compare_children xchildren ychildren
        end
      end
    end
  end
with compare_children (xs ys: list Info) {struct xs} :=
  match xs with
  | [] =>
    match ys with
    | [] => Eq
    | _ => Lt
    end
  | (x'::xs') =>
    match ys with
    | [] => Gt
    | (y'::ys') =>
      match compare_info x' y' with
      | Lt => Lt
      | Gt => Gt
      | Eq => compare_children xs' ys'
      end
    end
  end
.
```

The problem is I am getting the following error:

```
Recursive definition of compare_children is ill-formed.
In environment
compare_info : Info -> Info -> comparison
compare_children : list Info -> list Info -> comparison
xs : list Info
ys : list Info
x' : Info
xs' : list Info
y' : Info
ys' : list Info
Recursive call to compare_info has principal argument equal to 
"x'" instead of "xs'".
Recursive definition is:
"fun xs ys : list Info =>
 match xs with
 | [] => match ys with
         | [] => Eq
         | _ :: _ => Lt
         end
 | x' :: xs' =>
     match ys with
     | [] => Gt
     | y' :: ys' =>
         match compare_info x' y' with
         | Eq => compare_children xs' ys'
         | Lt => Lt
         | Gt => Gt
         end
     end
 end".
```

I have helped Coq along in a single recursive function before to see which element is the recursive one, but I don't think I have done it before with a mutually recursive function.

I would prefer not to use Program Fixpoint, since I have found in the past that this makes it really hard to prove things about the function.

I was wondering if there is another way to write this function in an acceptable way to Coq?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Regarding Program Fixpoint, if you use it to define a function `f`, you should prove a lemma `f_eq x : f x = <your original definition> x` afterwards. Basically, `Program` will manipulate your original definition to an annoying *but equivalent* format, and you can prove this. Then rewrite with `f_eq` every time `f` appears in a goal, and now it's not hard to prove things anymore. You can also prove a useful induction principle. [Here is an example.](https://gitlab.com/ana-borges/QRC1-Coq/-/blob/735aa275e82cff2df7873daf50f15439d0187e5a/theories/Closure.v#L46)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and also including the example, I'll also give this a try as an educational exercise.  Thank you so much <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type you are using is `Nested Inductive Type`. Your code is right, only one pure technical moment: definition of `compare_children` should be defined as local fixpoint, not a mutual one.

```
Fixpoint compare_info (x y: Info) {struct x} :=
  match x with
  | mkInfo xvalue xchildren xhash =>
    match y with
    | mkInfo yvalue ychildren yhash =>
      match Nat.compare xhash yhash with
      | Lt => Lt
      | Gt => Gt
      | Eq =>
        match Nat.compare xvalue yvalue with
        | Lt => Lt
        | Gt => Gt
        | Eq => ((fix compare_children (xs ys: list Info) {struct xs} :=
                   (match xs with
                    | [] =>
                      match ys with
                      | [] => Eq
                      | _ => Lt
                      end
                    | (x'::xs') =>
                      match ys with
                      | [] => Gt
                      | (y'::ys') =>
                        match compare_info x' y' with
                        | Lt => Lt
                        | Gt => Gt
                        | Eq => compare_children xs' ys'
                        end
                      end
                    end)) xchildren ychildren)
        end
      end
    end
  end.
```

For more information please see [Certified Programming with Dependent Types](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/) by Adam Chlipala. [Needed Chapter](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Cpdt.InductiveTypes.html) online (search for Nested Inductive). There is also an example of inductive principle for such types in the book.

Comment: Great answer and great reference, thank you so much <3